# Magento 1.9: Save custom image after click on Add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, product-view, image-upload

We have custom button in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , once user "**upload image or Add text**" & click on "**save design**", its saving **custom image** in server.

**save design** :

app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/template/aitcg - js_styles1.phtml

```
<script>

    var Aitcg_View_Abstract = Class.create(
    {

        _getControlPanelHtml: function()
        {
            if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
                return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                    '<button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}">SAVE DESIGN</button>' +               
                    '</div>';
            }
            return '';
        },

        initObservers: function()
    {
    if (this.config.editorEnabled && this.config.isUserLoggedIn == 'true') {
    $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
    },

    submitApply: function(event)
        {
            Event.stop(event);
            this.option.apply();        
        },

    }
</script>
```

we need similar feature for "**Add to cart**" button along with adding product to cart. so i am trying below code in addtocart.phtml  [ using same **id** as save design" ] & inserted above script in addtocart.phtml. but its not saving custom image when we click on "**add to cart**"

app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/template/catalog/product/view - addtocart.phtml

```
 <button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" 

onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span>ADD TO CART</span></button>
```

**save design** : https://pastebin.com/9h4QGuFK , **addtocart.phtml** : https://pastebin.com/RK71bjGJ

**Image**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addtocart.phtml change to this code:

```
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
        <button id="submit-editorApply-add-to-cart" type="button"  title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
```

In view.phtml remove :

```
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) { 

var form = this.form; 
var oldUrl = form.action; 

if (url) { 
form.action = url; 
} 
var e = null; 
try { 
this.form.submit(); 
} catch (e) { 
} 
this.form.action = oldUrl; 
if (e) { 
throw e; 
} 

if (button && button != 'undefined') { 
button.disabled = true; 
} 

}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

In js_style1 fix those function to:

```
initObservers: function() 
{ 
if (this.config.editorEnabled && this.config.isUserLoggedIn == 'true') { 
$('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.saveDesignBut.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
$('submit-editorApply-add-to-cart').observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
$('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
} 
}, 

    saveDesignBut: function(event) 
{ 
Event.stop(event); 
this.option.apply(); 
//jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").show(); 
},

submitApply: function(event) 
{ 
Event.stop(event); 
this.option.apply(); 
if(window.productAddToCartForm == 'undefined') { 
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form'); 
} else { 
var productAddToCartForm = window.productAddToCartForm; 
} 
productAddToCartForm.submit(); 
//jQuery("#aitcg-control-panel").show(); 
},
```

Comment: Thanks , its working for registered users , but not for guest users, can you please help for guest users also.....

Comment: js_styles1.phtml : https://pastebin.com/95mN1GfP ,  addtocart.phtml : https://pastebin.com/deZ6wFrL ,  view.phtml : https://pastebin.com/BWzmJm51

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved by adding a custom option of upload image in every product. This will get uploaded with every order and be there with every order. I saw your link, you can also add another custom option for text. This will work for you like charm..[image]